# MySQL logging confusion

Tags: mysql

I need to turn this on/enable it. I found some info on the net but am very confused now, I don't know where to start.

This is what I have so far. I logged onto MySQL as root and did:

```
 show variables like '%log%';
```

and got:

```
Variable_name                   | Value                            |
+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| back_log                        | 50                               |
| binlog_cache_size               | 32768                            |
| binlog_format                   | STATEMENT                        |
| expire_logs_days                | 10                               |
| general_log                     | ON                               |
| general_log_file                | /var/lib/mysql/helloise.log      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  | 1                                |
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  | OFF                              |
| innodb_log_buffer_size          | 1048576                          |
| innodb_log_file_size            | 5242880                          |
| innodb_log_files_in_group       | 2                                |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir       | ./                               |
| innodb_mirrored_log_groups      | 1                                |
| log                             | ON                               |
| log_bin                         | OFF                              |
| log_bin_trust_function_creators | OFF                              |
| log_bin_trust_routine_creators  | OFF                              |
| log_error                       | /var/log/mysql/error.log         |
| log_output                      | FILE                             |
| log_queries_not_using_indexes   | OFF                              |
| log_slave_updates               | OFF                              |
| log_slow_queries                | OFF                              |
| log_warnings                    | 1                                |
| max_binlog_cache_size           | 4294963200                       |
| max_binlog_size                 | 104857600                        |
| max_relay_log_size              | 0                                |
| relay_log                       |                                  |
| relay_log_index                 |                                  |
| relay_log_info_file             | relay-log.info                   |
| relay_log_purge                 | ON                               |
| relay_log_space_limit           | 0                                |
| slow_query_log                  | OFF                              |
| slow_query_log_file             | /var/lib/mysql/helloise-slow.log |
| sql_log_bin                     | ON                               |
| sql_log_off                     | OFF                              |
| sql_log_update                  | ON                               |
| sync_binlog                     | 0
```

I did: SET GLOBAL general_log = 1 to set general_log = ON. Will all queries be logged in /var/lib/mysql/helloise.log?

And when I try to access the mysql directory via `helloises@helloise:/var/lib$ cd mysql/` I get permission denied

and then I also have a log directory:

```
helloises@helloise:/var/log$
```

with a whole lot of log files ex: mysql.log

Which log file will contain my queries so I can track what my db is doing and see how long queries take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firs of all you got a permission denied because you hav not the privileges to read it. Try a

```
ls -l
```

on that file and see what permission are defined. Then yuo can use chmod to change permissions. Or simply try to read that file as a root user.

The general log is a logging feature for query log, reading, from guide:

> The general query log is a general record of what mysqld is doing. The
>   server writes information to this log when clients connect or
>   disconnect, and it logs each SQL statement received from clients. The
>   general query log can be very useful when you suspect an error in a
>   client and want to know exactly what the client sent to mysqld.

The error log:

> The error log contains information indicating when mysqld was started
>   and stopped and also any critical errors that occur while the server
>   is running. If mysqld notices a table that needs to be automatically
>   checked or repaired, it writes a message to the error log.

For understand the differences i suggest you to read  that site:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-logs.html

The file that contains the queries is the one in /var/lib/mysql/helloise.log

For the slow query logs you can check:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html

it logs all the query that take more time than long_query_time seconds (that variable must be defined by yourself). I don't found a way to show the execution time of a query, but check that page http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/log-destinations.html it could help you on how to configure general/slowquery logging.
Hope this help.

Comment: thank you managed to see what is in /var/lib/mysql/helloise.log..is there a way that i can manipulate what info gets sent to this file ex i need to track how long it takes to do a query,see the date ..it only lists Time,Id Command,Argument..any other info i can get here by configuring some settings? thanks :)